# How to get the URL of page from WebDriver instance that opens in new window

Tags: selenium, webdriver, ubuntu-12.04

I am doing automation using selenium. In a scenario when i click on the link from Page ABC, then it opens up the page DEF in a new window. Now, when i use the method `driver.getCurrentUrl()` then it gives me the URL of page ABC.

But i need to check the URL of page DEF. Please help me what should i do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first switch the control to newly open window and then use `driver.getCurrentUrl()`. It will gives you URL of newly opened window

first switch control using this

```
driver.switchTO().window("windowName/id");
```

then execute this to get the URL

```
driver.getCurrentUrl();
```

**Logic for switch control to popup**

```
Set<String> beforePopup = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
//click which causes to open new window
driver.fineElement(<By>).click();
// get all the window handles after the popup window appears 
Set<String> afterPopup = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
// remove all the handles from before the popup window appears afterPopup.removeAll(beforePopup); 
// there should be only one window handle left 
if(afterPopup.size() == 1) 
{ 
        driver.switchTo().window((String)afterPopup.toArray()[0]); 
}
```

Comment: but how do i get the id/name of the newly opened window?

Comment: will driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandle());work in this case?

Comment: In firebug console type window.name it will give name of that window. otherwise follow this http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-switch-control-to-pop-up-window.html

Comment: No Vipin it won't. driver.getWindowHandle() give the current window handle but not newly opened window's. driver.getWindowHandles() returns the set of window handles which includes newly opened window as well as mail window.

Comment: @vipin8169 check if driver.getwindowhandles() is helpful.

Comment: i tried the following snippet:-

'String mainWindowHandle=driver.getWindowHandle();
  Set s = driver.getWindowHandles();
  Iterator ite = s.iterator();
  while(ite.hasNext()) {
   System.out.println(ite.toString());
   System.out.println(ite.toString());
                       }'
it gave me the following horrible output repeated infinte times
java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator@4b5386c2
java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator@4b5386c2

Comment: PS:- i am not able to format the code by using ' ' in the comments :(

Comment: Try something like this 

 Set<String> beforePopup = driver.getWindowHandles();
   // get all the window handles after the popup window appears
      Set<String> afterPopup = driver.getWindowHandles();
      // remove all the handles from before the popup window appears
      afterPopup.removeAll(beforePopup);

      // there should be only one window handle left
      if(afterPopup.size() == 1) {
       driver.switchTo().window((String)afterPopup.toArray()[0]);
      }

Comment: I've added above coment in my answer just go through it.

Comment: what is the need of using `(String)afterNewWindow.toArray()[0]`

why can't i simply use `(String)afterNewWindow` , why is the array conversion required here?

Comment: because that it is set, but we need to pass String as a parameter to driver.switchTo().window(string); 

set may contains more than one value. that's why we're casting to array and using first value in that array and casting that first value as String

Comment: but actually that set has only one value left, what we are doing is just a precation. isn't it?

Comment: No, it is not. If we do that it will return object but not value.

Answer (score 2):

Try to switch to the new window DEF using

```
  driver.switchto().window(DEF)
```

and then use

```
  driver.getCurrentUrl().
```

Comment: i quoted it as an example.
use driver.getwindowhandles() and find out the new window name.